# How to read txt file from jar and docker opt directory

Tags: java, docker

I need to write functional which could to process not only jar file like resource/config/file.txt but also file which located in opt docker directory.
I have first case where txt file is located in jar

```
 try (InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resource/config/file")) {
        if (inputStream == null) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("can't find configuration file");
        }
```

and its work,but if I try to put /opt/docker/conf its does not work

I have second case where txt file is located in docker opt directory

```
try (Reader reader = new FileReader("/opt/docker/conf"))
```

its Work

Is there a way to combine both cases?

Comment: Sure. If the first approach gives you a null input stream, you try and check if that file system path works. So: yes, there are ways to combine your two pieces of code. The real question is: what prevents you from working on this yourself?

Comment: first case cant find txt file outside jar and second case cant fint txt file in jar) so i would like to find Object which can to combine both functional

Comment: Again: what prevents you from writing a method that KNOWS about both these places, and checks for each, in your preferred order whether they work? Or are you asking how to create an interface that works with InputStream as well as with Reader???

Comment: of cource i can write that method,and yes i asking about how to create common interface for both cases. Really java has not that?